# What is the advantage of std::ref and std::reference_wrapper compared to regular references?

Tags: c++, reference, reference-wrapper

I have some questions regarding this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
template <typename T> void foo ( T x )
{
    auto r=ref(x);
    cout<<boolalpha;
    cout<<is_same<T&,decltype(r)>::value;
}
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    foo (x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
false
```

I want to know, if `std::ref` doesn't return the reference of an object, then what does it do? Basically, what is the difference between:

```
T x;
auto r = ref(x);
```

and

```
T x;
T &y = x;
```

Also, I want to know why does this difference exist? Why do we need `std::ref` or `std::reference_wrapper` when we have references (i.e. `T&`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is tr1::reference\_wrapper useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193703/how-is-tr1reference-wrapper-useful)

Comment: Hint: what happens if you do `x = y;`  in both cases?

Comment: In addition to my duplicate flag (last comment): See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270810/difference-between-and-stdreference-wrapper and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26766939/difference-between-stdreference-wrapper-and-simple-pointer

Comment: @anderas it's not about usefulness, it's about the difference mainly

Comment: @CppNITR Then see the questions I linked a few seconds before your comment. Especially the second one is useful.

Comment: @anderas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270810/difference-between-and-stdreference-wrapper is quite close but the response and answers are not satisfactory
could u explain this question

Comment: Whenever I look at one of these things, and think about what its implications might be on the design on complex (especially generic) data structures - I sigh in despair of how richly hard of a language C++ really is.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Well `ref` constructs an object of the appropriate `reference_wrapper` type to hold a reference to an object. Which means when you apply:

```
auto r = ref(x);
```

This returns a `reference_wrapper` and not a direct reference to `x` (ie `T&`). This `reference_wrapper` (ie `r`) instead holds `T&`.

A `reference_wrapper` is very useful when you want to emulate a `reference` of an object which can be copied (it is both *copy-constructible* and *copy-assignable*).

In C++, once you create a reference (say `y`) to an object (say `x`), then `y` and `x` share the same *base address*. Furthermore, `y` cannot refer to any other object. Also you cannot create an *array of references* ie code like this will throw an error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=5, y=7, z=8;
    int& arr[] {x,y,z};    // error: declaration of 'arr' as array of references
    return 0;
}
```

However this is legal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>  // for reference_wrapper
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=5, y=7, z=8;
    reference_wrapper<int> arr[] {x,y,z};
    for (auto a: arr)
        cout << a << " ";
    return 0;
}
/* OUTPUT:
5 7 8
*/
```

Talking about your problem with `cout << is_same<T&,decltype(r)>::value;`, the solution is:

```
cout << is_same<T&,decltype(r.get())>::value;  // will yield true
```

Let me show you a program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    int x=5, y=7;
    reference_wrapper<int> r=x;   // or auto r = ref(x);
    cout << is_same<int&, decltype(r.get())>::value << "\n";
    cout << (&x==&r.get()) << "\n";
    r=y;
    cout << (&y==&r.get()) << "\n";
    r.get()=70;
    cout << y;
    return 0;
}
/* Ouput:
true
true
true
70
*/
```

See here we get to know three things:

1. A `reference_wrapper` object (here `r`) can be used to create an *array of references* which was not possible with `T&`.
2. `r` actually acts like a real reference (see how `r.get()=70` changed the value of `y`).
3. `r` is not same as `T&` but `r.get()` is. This means that `r` holds `T&` ie as its name suggests is a *wrapper around a reference* `T&`.

I hope this answer is more than enough to explain your doubts.

Comment: 1: No, a `reference_wrapper` can be _reassigned_, but it cannot "hold reference to more than one objects". 2/3: Fair point about where `.get()` is appropriate - _but_ unsuffixed `r` _can_ be used the same as `T&` in cases where `r`'s conversion `operator` can be invoked unambiguously - so no need to call `.get()` in many cases, including several in your code (which is difficult to read due to lack of spaces).

Comment: @underscore_d `reference_wrapper` can hold an array of references if you are not sure then you can try it yourself. 
Plus `.get()` is used when you want to change the value of the object the `reference_wrapper` is holding` ie `r=70` is illegal so you have to use `r.get()=70`.
Try yourself !!!!!!

Comment: Show me a single `reference_wrapper` holding more than one reference.

Comment: Not really. First, let's use accurate wording. You are showing a reference_wrapper holding _a reference to an array_ - not a reference_wrapper that itself _contains "reference to more than one objects"_. The wrapper only holds one reference. Secondly, I can get a native reference to an array just fine - are you sure you didn't just forget the (parentheses) around `int a[4]{1, 2, 3, 4}; int (&b)[4] = a;`? reference_wrapper is not special here since native `T&` _does_ work.

Comment: Like an array is used to hold one or more object, a `reference_wrapper` to an array will also hold references to multiple objects. Only because it refers to an array doesn't mean that it doesn't refer to more than one object (in fact it actually does). Of course it's not a special case, rather `array of references` is a special case of `reference_wrapper` (which I have shown in my answer)

Comment: "This reference_wrapper (ie r) instead holds T&" - doesn't it hold `T*` ?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Yes :-) but to be precise, _effective_ result aside, _itself_ only refers to one object. Anyway, you're of course right that unlike a normal ref, the `wrapper` can go in a container. This is handy, but I think people misinterpret this as more advanced than it really is. If I want an array of 'refs', I usually skip the middleman with `vector<Item *>`, which is what the `wrapper` boils down to... and hope the anti-pointer purists don't find me. The convincing use-cases for it are different and more complex.

Comment: @M.M, yes actually it holds `T*` which is why it is able to refer to more than one object but it's behaviour altogether is more similar to `T&` than `T*`

Comment: "A reference_wrapper is very useful when you want to emulate a reference of an object which can be copied." But doesn't that defeat the purpose of a reference? You're referring to the actual thing. That's what a reference IS. A reference that can be copied, seems pointless, because if you want to copy it, then you don't want a reference in the first place, you should just copy the original object. It seems like an unnecessary layer of complexity to solve a problem which doesn't need to exist in the first place.

Comment: @stu Coping a reference is useful. This is because you are not copying the value of the reference, but cloning the reference as (yet another) reference to the original object. This is much like coping a pointer. A reason to use `reference_wrapper<T>` over `T *` is to make it crystal clear that `delete` should not be used.

Comment: so.... why can't you just make a reference to a reference? int a = 1; int &b = a; int &c = b;

Answer (score 63):

`std::reference_wrapper` is recognized by standard facilities to be able to pass objects by reference in pass-by-value contexts.

For example, `std::bind` can take in the `std::ref()` to something, transmit it by value, and unpacks it back into a reference later on.

```
void print(int i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int i = 10;

    auto f1 = std::bind(print, i);
    auto f2 = std::bind(print, std::ref(i));

    i = 20;

    f1();
    f2();
}
```

This snippet outputs :

```
10
20
```

The value of `i` has been stored (taken by value) into `f1` at the point it was initialized, but `f2` has kept an `std::reference_wrapper` by value, and thus behaves like it took in an `int&`.

Comment: @CppNITR sure ! Give me a moment to assemble a small demo :)

Comment: what about the difference between T& & ref(T)

Comment: @CppNITR `std::ref(T)` returns a `std::reference_wrapper`. It's little more than a wrapped pointer, but is recognize by the library as "hey, I'm supposed to be a reference ! Please turn me back into one once you're done passing me around".

Answer (score 45):

A reference (`T&` or `T&&`) is a special element in C++ language. It allows to manipulate an object *by reference* and has special use cases in the language. For example, you cannot create a standard container to hold references: `vector<T&>` is ill formed and generates a compilation error.

A `std::reference_wrapper` on the other hand is a C++ object able to hold a reference. As such, you can use it in standard containers.

`std::ref` is a standard function that returns a `std::reference_wrapper` on its argument. In the same idea, `std::cref` returns `std::reference_wrapper` to a const reference.

One interesting property of a `std::reference_wrapper`, is that it has an `operator T& () const noexcept;`. That means that **even if it is a true object**, it can be automatically converted to the reference that it is holding. So:

- as it is a copy assignable object, it can be used in containers or in other cases where references are not allowed
- thanks to its `operator T& () const noexcept;`, it can be used anywhere you could use a reference, because it will be automatically converted to it.

Comment: upvoted mainly because mention of `operator T& ()` which other 2 answers failed to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Added an example to show the difference in value you get when you pass the T& and ref(T) arguments in the bind function.

std::bind copies the argument provided unless it is passed by std::ref()/std::cref().

```
    void f(int r1, int& r2, int w1, int& w2)
    {
        std::cout << r1 << r2 << w1 << w2; // 5 5 10 10
        r1 = 9, r2 = 9, w1 = 9, w2 = 9;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int w1 = 5, w2 = 5, n1 = 5, n2 = 5;
        int& r1 = n1;
        int& r2 = n2;
        std::function<void()> bound_f = std::bind(f, r1, r2, std::ref(w1), std::ref(w2)); 
        r1 = 10, r2 = 10, w1 = 10, w2 = 10;
        bound_f();                          //  5  5 10 10
        std::cout << r1 << r2 << w1 << w2;  // 10 10 10  9
    }
```